# Jump directly to certain parts of a function

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I would like a hint on how to complete this puzzle. I need to be able to print what is normally printed out in reverse. Normally this prints, `hello there`. I need it to print `there hello`. I am only allowed to add code where it is commented.

Here are some of my thoughts that don't work.

- I thought about using the heap to store some data but I can't because `stdlib.h` is not included.
- Can't use `goto` because I can't add labels and what I would `goto` is all in one line
- Can't use recursion because there are no input parameters and no global variables to modify.
- Can't possibly think of a way assembly could help but hey maybe?
- I can't do anything obvious like just calling `printf`'s and quitting the program early.
- Thoughts on something to do with function pointers? I still don't see how they would help.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
void f1(); void f2(); void f3();

int main() { f1(); printf("\n"); return 0; }

void f1() { f2(); printf(" there "); }

void f2() { f3(); printf(" hello "); }

void f3(){
    int x;
    //Can add whatever under here
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this programming puzzle?

Comment: An extra challenge given in class. No real purpose other than that.

Comment: @strangequestions based on your comments below, it looks like you may have left out several important details in your question.  It would help if you included the exact text of the problem statement as you received it without paraphrasing.

Comment: `printf("there hello\n"); exit(0);` ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because programming puzzles are off-topic for Stack Overflow. You might be able to get help on Programming Puzzles & Code Golf: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com

Comment: If this was 32-bit code and I have a hunch it is based on the x variable a simple way to do it with no optimizations would be 
    `int x;`
    `x = (&x)[2];`
    `(&x)[2]=(&x)[6];`
    `(&x)[6]=x;` . 32-bit, Undefined behavior, relies on specific stack layout, assumes frame pointer, and requires one to compile with no optimizations. Fugly

Comment: @immibis : One rule he has is _I can't do anything obvious like just calling printf's and quitting the program early._

Comment: `}` `#include <unistd.h>` `void _start() {write(1, "there hello", 11); _exit(0);` ? Depending on compiler

Answer (score 2):

I think the only purpose of `int x;` is to get the stack pointer without using inline assembly.

The solution on how to do this exactly will depend on your platform, the compiler you use and the optimization levels you have used.

I would say first you need to analyze the call stack.

You can do this -

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i< 10; i++) {
     printf ("%p\n", *(void**)((char*) &x - i * 8)); // I am assumming 64 bit machines. If 32 bit replace 8 with 4
}
```

This will give you the top 10 8 byte values on the stack. Now you need to find the two that look like return addresses. One way to recognize them would be to print the function pointer value of f1 and f2 and see the values close to them.

You now know the indexes where they are stored. Just go ahead and swap them.

For swapping them, say the indices are 12 and 14.

Then you can do this -

```
*(void**)&x = *((void**)&x + 12);
*((void**)&x + 12) = *((void**)&x + 14);
*((void**)&x + 14) = *(void**)&x;
```

Also make sure you don't change the stack layout once you get the indices. This means don't remove/add any variables. Don't apply the & operator to any new variables (or remove from any) and don't remove any function calls.

Also another suggestion - Instead of using int x, you could declare another unsigned long long y and use that for the swap instead. Because it would have enough bytes to hold a pointer (on 64 bit machines). Usually there will be padding in case of int x too which should save you from the problem but rather be safe.

Comment: How do I swap them once I identify them without inline assembly?

Comment: @strangequestions If you review the comment I made under your question I give you a hint how to do that using the address of the `x` variable on the stack. Because it is on the stack you can utillize undefined behaviour to gain access to the stack by thinking of the address of `x` as being a pointer to an array of 32-bit integers. That allows you to access the stack as if it were an array. Swapping values in an array is quite easy.

Comment: @strangequestions Edited answer to show how to swap

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternate solution that doesn't depend on stack manipulation. The fundamental 'trick' is that the program provides its own implementation of `printf()` instead of using the standard library's.

Tested on gcc (Mingw, Linux x86 and Linux x64) and MSVC:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void f1(); void f2(); void f3();

int main() { f1(); printf("\n"); return 0; }

void f1() { f2(); printf(" there "); }

void f2() { f3(); printf(" hello "); }

void f3(){
    int x;
    //Can add whatever under here
    return;
}

void putstr( char const* s)
{
    for (;*s;++s) {
        putchar(*s);
    }    
}


int printf(char const* fmt, ...)
{
    static char const* pushed_fmt = 0;

    if (*fmt == '\n') {
        putstr(fmt);
        return 0;
    }

    if (pushed_fmt == 0) { 
        pushed_fmt = fmt;
        return 0;
    }

    putstr(fmt);
    putstr(pushed_fmt);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that give multiple definition errors at link time? Or `printf`is actually a weak symbol? (does VC++ even *have* weak symbols?)

Comment: Also, the text of the challenge says "I am only allowed to add code where it is commented." Unless you argue that the final closing brace is the same one as the one under the comment in the question text, which *would* be a nice workaround. :-)

Comment: @MatteoItalia : I infer that the code had to be inserted after the comment and before the `}`. I may also be under the impression (maybe mistaken) that something like `putchar` isn't allowed. You could have just used `putchar` to output all the characters and call `exit`. I inferred this from the  _I can't do anything obvious LIKE just calling printf's and quitting the program early._ . The ambiguity though is that it has the word `obvious`. The question itself is too vague on requirements. It would be nice to see the exact challenge and the exact constraints of the challenge.

Comment: @MatteoItalia - I'm not sure how much I'd argue with my instructor, but I would try to make that argument about the brace. MSVC has always treated symbols in object files as having a higher "priority" over symbols in a library. In fact, I believe that if the same symbol exists in more than one library, MSVC uses the first one it encounters without complaint.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: personally, I don't consider this solution to be in the same category as just printing the desired output and exiting.  But I'm also pretty sure that the instructor is looking for the stack manipulation solution. If that's the case, the assignment should simply state: "fill in the code to manipulate the stack to get the desired result".

Comment: @MichaelBurr : yes I concur, I've seen related questions like this and usually it is part of a course that has as much to do with understanding how generated code may work and learning about the call stack, stack frames etc. I like your answer. I just wish the OP would post the challenge as given to them. Was requested yesterday in the comments. As it is beyond this being code golf the question is just too vague IMHO. Too many assumptions to make a specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the idea is that from f3() you have the return addresses on the stack all the way up, and nothing has been printed so far.

You'd have to play with the stack contents so that f3() returns into f1(), which would then return into f2().

Can you take it from here? Depending on the compiler, there will be different ways to accomplish this. Inline assembly might or might not be required.

EDIT: specifically for GCC, see [the GCC return address intrinsics](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html).

Comment: ISO C standard has no strict definitions about compiler stack implementations. In general case **it is impossible** to modify return value from stack using vanilla C if we know nothing about implementation itself.

Comment: I have my doubts that stack manipulation is the answer to this problem. I am using GCC to compile if that gives you anything on the stack implementation.

Comment: If you don't want to manipulate the stack, you could use assembly to just exit the program directly from f3(), never returning.

Comment: @strangequestions. Well, in this case answer is obvious. Just modify return value (switch f2 and f3) from stack and problem solved. Maybe it would be worth to mention that you are using **GCC** in your question because it changes a lot of things.

Comment: A less pleasing solution would be to go into a 'forever loop' at the end of f3(), never returning. Could be done without assembly.

Comment: f1() calling f2() calling f3() kind of hints at stack manipulation. A temporary variable, too. The solution I'm thinking of involves swapping two addresses on the stack, so a temporary would be needed.

Comment: @FREE_AND_OPEN_SOURCE Indeed.  The last time I checked, the standard does not mention the word `stack` even once.

Comment: Why the [assembly] tag if it's not for an assembly class? :)

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev why would you need a temporary variable for return address swapping? There are registers available.

Comment: If you want to do that with C intrinsics as opposed to assembly (which is possible in GCC), you need a temporary.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a portable solution that doesn't mess with the stack and return addresses. Most probably not what was expected by who wrote that challenge, but it's way more fun to think out of the box.

```
void f3(){
    int x;
    //Can add whatever under here
    static count = 0;
    static char buf[256];
    if(count==0) {
        setvbuf(stdout, buf, _IOFBF, sizeof(buf));
        int atexit (void (*func)(void)); 
        atexit(f3);
        count = 1;
    } else {
        const char *src = " there  hello \n";
        char *dest = buf;
        for(; *src;) *dest++ = *src++;
    } 
}
```

http://ideone.com/S4zMHP

This works by first using `setvbuf` to replace the `stdout` buffer with one that we provide, and switching it to full buffering (instead of line buffering) to make sure that no flush happens before the end of the program (notice that no output has been written yet, so calling `setvbuf` is legal). We also call `atexit` to make sure we get called before the end of the program (we don't have `stdlib.h`, but who needs headers when the required prototypes are already known).

When we are called again (thanks to `atexit`), the two `printf` have been called, but the buffer hasn't been flushed yet. We outright replace its content with the string of our interest (which is just as big as what has been written), and return. The subsequent implicit `fclose` will dump out the modified content of our buffer instead of what was written by the `printf`.